# Using same model class in two app realm giving error while migration "Illegal Argument: Invalid format of Realm file."

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I am Converting CSV file to realm file on **APP ONE** then shipping this as the primary database in the **APP TWO** and setting as default database using

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
    if (isFirstRun)
    {



        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .migration(new in.webic.oralcalculations.Row())
                .assetFile(context, "Default.realm")
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .build();

        realm = realm.getInstance(config);
        realm.close();


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

I am Using same **Model** Class in both the applications

```
import io.realm.DynamicRealm;
import io.realm.RealmMigration;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.RealmSchema;

public class Row extends RealmObject implements RealmMigration {
public Row(){}

private int id;
private int course;
private int qp1;
private int qp2;
private int col5;
private int col6;
private int col7;






public Row(int id, int course, int qp1, int qp2, int col5, int col6,int col7) {
    this.id = id;
    this.course = course;
    this.qp1 = qp1;
    this.qp2 = qp2;
    this.col5 = col5;
    this.col6 = col6;
    this.col7 = col7;
}

public int getCol7() {
    return col7;
}

public void setCol7(int col7) {
    this.col7 = col7;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(int course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public int getQp1() {
    return qp1;
}

public void setQp1(int qp1) {
    this.qp1 = qp1;
}

public int getQp2() {
    return qp2;
}

public void setQp2(int qp2) {
    this.qp2 = qp2;
}

public int getCol5() {
    return col5;
}

public void setCol5(int col5) {
    this.col5 = col5;
}

public int getCol6() {
    return col6;
}

public void setCol6(int col6) {
    this.col6 = col6;
}


@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
}
}
```

Yet i am getting an error stating

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.webic.oralcalculations/in.webic.oralcalculations.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Argument: Invalid format of Realm file.

I am not able to debug the deference in the format because i am using same model class what could be the step I am missing ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ....why do you need an empty migration? that does not look right

Comment: @EpicPandaForce there is data in the assetFile file which i am transferring as my default db, what is empty i couldn't understand

Comment: issue has been solved the version of the realm in both the app was different,making them same in the gradle solved it